# Embedded (non-ROS) -> ROS over Ethernet

Tags: ros, ethernet, embedded

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an embedded device not supported by ROS but which runs a Linux variant.
I want to connect this to my ROS Groovy machine via Ethernet but not sure on the best approach - however I was thinking TCP would be ideal.

How should i connect these devices and are there any examples from which I can work from?
I.e. How can i communicate between them over Ethernet?

Cheers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99931/embedded-(non-ros)--%3E-ros-over-ethernet/) by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 327 on 2013-11-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Started with ROSSerial but ran into problems as this was not designed for 32-bit systems.

Solution was to communicate using Python sockets:
http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-programming-tutorial/

The embedded device was setup as a server, and the ROS machine connects as a client to send commands to the embedded device.

---

Originally posted by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) with karma: 327 on 2013-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have basically two way of doing this:

1. You can compile roscomm on your embedded device. It is enough to send ROS messages over the network.
2. You have no way to compile roscomm on this embedded device so you need to use an alternative communication channel TCP or UDP being probably the easiest way to go.

1 is better but require more work whereas 2 is probably easier but will induce a delay in the communication...

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on 2013-11-12**:
Would you suggest following a setup like the link below for adding the packages to my environment?
http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/cturtle(2f)Installation(2f)Windows.html

Do i only need the ros_comm lib?
Although the tutorial is for Windows, i think the concept still holds on my unsupported hardware

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-11-12**:
Well compiling ROS by hands on your Linux variant will definitively be easier than compiling ROS on Windows I guess. For instance see, http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [ros-embedded SIG](http://wiki.ros.org/sig/Embedded), which might be a good point to start. Additionally, the [ros-c](http://wiki.ros.org/rosc) effort intends to bring a full (enough) ROS implementation to both Linux-based and bare-metal embedded systems. Another client library focused on embedded use is [µROSnode](http://wiki.ros.org/%C2%B5ROSnode).

Regarding your comment on 'unsupported hardware': as long as you are able to use any of the existing client libraries (or port them), getting something to work shouldn't be too involved.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-11-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1